# converting java sha512crypt to c#

Tags: c#, java, encryption, salt, sha512

I am trying to duplicate the following JAVA code into C# but I don't think I'm doing it right o_o

(The code is taken from ftp://ftp.arlut.utexas.edu/pub/java_hashes/Sha512Crypt.java)

JAVA variables:

ctx, alt_ctx = MessageDigest

key          = String (the password to hash)

salt         = String (salt to add to the hash)

```
        /*                  ---JAVA---                    //
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ctx.reset();

        ctx.update(key, 0, key.length);
        ctx.update(salt, 0, salt.length);

        alt_ctx.reset();
        alt_ctx.update(key, 0, key.length);
        alt_ctx.update(salt, 0, salt.length);
        alt_ctx.update(key, 0, key.length);

        alt_result = alt_ctx.Digest();
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
```

C# variables:

ctx, alt_ctx = HashAlgorithm (SHA512Managed)

key and salt are same as in JAVA...

```
 //                       --- C# EQUIV ? ---                    //
        int TESTINGINT;
        ctx = null;
        ctx = new SHA512Managed();
        ctx.TransformBlock(key, 0, key.Length, key, 0);
        ctx.TransformBlock(salt, 0, salt.Length, salt, 0);

        alt_ctx = null;
        alt_ctx = new SHA512Managed();

        alt_ctx.TransformBlock(key, 0, key.Length, key, 0);
        alt_ctx.TransformBlock(salt, 0, salt.Length, salt, 0);
        alt_ctx.TransformBlock(key, 0, key.Length, key, 0);

        alt_result = alt_ctx.TransformFinalBlock(key, 0, key.Length); //most likely wrong here

        //?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????//
```

Like I said, pretty sure this is wrong... Wondering if anyone knows the exact translation.

I've also been looking at http://www.obviex.com/samples/hash.aspx for some help. This however does not give me the same output and does not have any # rounds to do.

Given the word "beta" I'm trying to ultimately replicate the following (one line)

$6$rounds=60000$ZIFtW/dNUcD/k$O57sTkYwuRpQcgpnIdKLShfCVR7.vGzfMhvvWn7Mg8trGJsWADChhs6S5ONybnSBWHEHIQKw66a4i/YrA4y/y1

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can't you tell whether or not it is "wrong" by running the code and seeing if it works?  Have you tried that?  What was the result?

Comment: Your C# code is incomplete.  You have variables that have not even been declared.

Comment: later on in my code I'm running into argument exceptions, so something is not right.

Comment: @Ramhound This code is not my full program, I have delcared all my variables and I could post that if you would like to see...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after doing some thorough testing, I've fixed my C# to the following which seems to be the equivalent...

```
ctx = new SHA512Managed();

byte[] digestA = new byte[key.Length + salt.Length];

ctx.TransformBlock(key, 0, key.Length, digestA, 0);
ctx.TransformBlock(salt, 0, salt.Length, digestA, key.Length);

byte[] digestB = new byte[key.Length * 2 + salt.Length];

ctx.TransformBlock(key, 0, key.Length, digestB, 0);
ctx.TransformBlock(salt, 0, salt.Length, digestB, key.Length);
ctx.TransformBlock(key, 0, key.Length, digestB, key.Length + salt.Length);

alt_ctx = new SHA512Managed();

alt_result = alt_ctx.ComputeHash(digestB);
```